# Изменение имени кнопки при нажатии

Tags: java, swing

**Предыстория:** Пишем на занятиях RPG. Игровое поле реализовано так: двумерный массив с разного типа плитками, каждому типу плитки соответствует собственный символ(чтобы было можно, например, считать карту из txt). Создаю оконный редактор карт, в котором каждой из плиток соответствует кнопка с названием из символа соответствующей плитки(выглядит по типу Сапёра). Реализовано должно быть так, чтобы множество из n символов плиток гонялось по кругу за n нажатий на кнопку.

**Вопрос:** Как передать обработчику нажатия на кнопку информацию о нажатой кнопке? Экземпляр кнопки? В идеале(в идеале, потому что вся оставшаяся часть редактора уже написана из таких соображений) представляется что-то подобное:

```
public class TileButtonsListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (currentButtonsName()) {//передаем в switch имя нажатой кнопки
            case "#":
                setСurrentButtonsName("O");//присваиваем нажатой кнопке новое имя 
                break;
            case "O":
                setСurrentButtonsName("B");
                break;
            case "B":
                setСurrentButtonsName("#");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо забирать [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#source) из ивента. Выглядеть будет так

```
public class TileButtonsListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Button btn = (Button) e.getSource();
        switch (currentButtonsName()) { //передаем в switch имя нажатой кнопки
        case "#":
            btn.setText("O"); //присваиваем нажатой кнопке новое имя 
            break;
        case "O":
            btn.setText("B");
            break;
        case "B":
            btn.setText("#");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
```

Comment: На самом деле, так не получается, как ни печально. Вероятно, `btn` не инициализируется текущей кнопкой, а только тем в этой кнопке, что наследовано от `Object`. При попытке `btn.getName()` кидается `NPE`.

Comment: Вы лисенер этот вешаете на что? На JButton или что-то кастомное?

Comment: На JButton. Нодумываю теперь переопределить метод getSource в наследованном от ActionEvent классе, чтобы возвращал JButton

Comment: А что вам возваращает getSource ? Вы не должны переопределять ActionListener, потому что не вы кидаете этот ивент

Comment: Я допустил где-то ошибку. Все заработало так, как я и хотел. Спасибо Вам.